# How do I reset the default Play database?

Tags: playframework

I am using the default database in a Play 2 application:

```
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
```

I thought this database was supposed to be in-memory and that the data would disappear in between runs of the application, but the data seems to persist somewhere even after I shut off the app.

Where is the data being persisted and how can I clean out the database?

Comment: That is a bizarre behavior.  Just to clarify, you are killing the Java process that is executing the Play application, and not just closing a web browser, right?

Comment: @DavidKaczynski I am using ctrl-D to stop the application that was started using the run command in the console. The database also persists after closing the play console completely. Restarting my PC is the only thing that seems to reset the db.

Answer (score 1):

In response to your comment, Ctrl-D in the console doesn't terminate the Play application; it runs the application in the background and makes the console available again (that's why closing the console didn't terminate the application).  I'm not sure about non-Linux operating systems, but in Linux, you need to use ctrl-C in the console or `kill <pid>` in another console to terminate the Play application.

Answer (score 0):

accoding to h2 site:

> By default, closing the last connection to a database closes the database. For an in-memory database, this means the content is lost. To keep the database open, add ;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1 to the database URL. To keep the content of an in-memory database as long as the virtual machine is alive, use jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1.

this may there is more than one connection to your database.

Comment: Is there any way to check the connections?